# css problems for my thumbnail

Tags: html, css

I'm trying  to create a thumbnail for each of my projects in my projects list (see the model I made in Illustrator bellow), but what I got is not exactly what I want (see the current result at: http://kevinduguay.ca/fr/projets).

The code:

```
<article class="projet">
    <img src="img/vignette.jpg" alt="paranorium">
    <div class="infoReduit">
        <h2>Paranorium</h2>
        <p>Jeu de survie/horreur fait avec Unity 3D en UnityScript</p>
        <b>Réalisé en 2014</b>
    </div>
</article>


/* line 94, ../sass/projets.scss */
article section .projet {
  width: 55%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  background: #f4f5f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* line 104, ../sass/projets.scss */
article section .projet img {
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
}
/* line 114, ../sass/projets.scss */
article section .projet .infoReduit {
  float: left;
  width: 56%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  background: red;
}
/* line 121, ../sass/projets.scss */
article section .projet .infoReduit h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
}
/* line 130, ../sass/projets.scss */
article section .projet .infoReduit p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7a717c;
  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
/* line 140, ../sass/projets.scss */
article section .projet .infoReduit b {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #7a717c;
  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
}
```

I got two problemes:

-making my "infoReduit" div height:100; doesn't make it fit the article in height. I wnat that so that if I reduce the image size, than the "infoReduit" div will get resized too.

-I want to make the  stick to the bottom of my "infoReduit" div.

Comment: don't quite understand your problem. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want that my img to stick to the left and that the div takes all the rest of the remaining space BUT that if I put a margin-left, it would just leave a little space between the img and the div, but the still should take the remaining space. AND all that without resizing the parent div of the picture and the div. Finally, the <b> should stick to the bottom of his div.

The big problem is that... well... it's not working.

Comment: I found the solution. Here it is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here it is:

```
<article class="projet">
    <img src="img/vignette.jpg" alt="paranorium">
    <h2>Paranorium</h2>
    <div class="infoReduit">
        <p>Jeu de survie/horreur fait avec Unity 3D en UnityScript</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoTotal">
        <p>Paranorium est un jeu de survie/horror où vous devez survivre dans un labyrinth remplie de pièges mortels, tout en étant poursuivit par un ennemi malicieux et dangereux que vous ne pouvez ni semer ou tuer...</p>
        <p>Role dans le projet: Directeur Technique</p>
        <p>Technologie utilisée: Unity 3D, UnityScript(Javascript), Maya</p>
        <p>Aptitudes dévelloppées: Communiquation en équipe</p>
    </div>
    <b>Réalisé en 2014</b>
</article>


article section .projet {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  width: 535px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  background: #f4f5f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

article section .projet img {
  width: 180px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

article section .projet h2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
  right: 0;
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

article section .projet .infoReduit {
  position: absolute;
  color: #7a717c;
  margin-top: 36px;
  right: 0;
  width: 350px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

article section .projet .infoReduit p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
}

article section .projet .infoTotal {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 36px;
  right: 0;
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0;
  -o-transition-delay: 0;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

article section .projet .infoTotal p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f4f5f5;
  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
}

article section .projet .infoTotal p:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

article section .projet b {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 0;
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the thumbnail a background image of the , resize the div and the image will scale.

give infoReduit relative positioning and stick the image div with absolute.

```
.infoReduit {
 position:relative;
}
#paranorium {
 width:???;
 height:???;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 background-imgage:url('img/vignette.jpg');
}
```

Comment: The probleme with your solution is that, in my case, the image MUST be an img and not set in the CSS, so if you have an other way that use the img, it would be better.

Comment: Why can it not be set in CSS?  Is this a dynamic page where the image `src` changes often?  Is the page generated by a script like PHP?  Are you opposed to a JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this css below:

```
article section .projet{
    display:table;
}
article section .projet img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* float: left; */
    display: table-cell;
}

article section .projet .infoReduit {
    /* float: left; */
    width: 58%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

if any problem replay me

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/9jhs7nga/2/)

Comment: I tried your solution, but there still is a few problemes.
-There is space between the img and the div that I want to reduce alot. The best would be that my div is stick to the img and take all the reste of the parent div for his width and that a margin-left would push it a littl bit without screwing everythings up.
-The <b> must stick to the bottom of the div.

Comment: use this css for image width---- article section .projet img{width:calc(100% - 20px);}    please vote my answer

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but this is not what I'm looking for.

I want that my img to stick to the left and that the div takes all the rest of the remaining space BUT that if I put a margin-left, it would just leave a little space between the img and the div, but the still should take the remaining space. AND all that without resizing the parent div of the picture and the div. Finally, the <b> should stick to the bottom of his div.